# Is there notation denoting that one sigma-algebra is sub-sigma-algebra of another?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

The question is self-describing.

Comment: I think this is reasonable: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sub-Sigma-Algebra.

Comment: @unit3000-21 the same as for sets?

Comment: because they are essentially sets

Comment: I believe so.  This seems to be confirmed in two other books I have.  But don't try to generalize "because they are essentially sets," since for groups, you will see $H \leq G$ or but (probably) not $H \subset G$.

Comment: @unit3000-21 By definition it is a collection of subsets of a set stable under finitely many set operations + contains all infinite unions of subsets from it.

Comment: @unit3000-21 if you put what you wrote as an answer - I will accept it. Note: later I took a look at filtration for martingales - and this notation was used as from definition.

Comment: As much as I'd love a +15, the content of Nate's answer below is essentially what I wrote in the comment, so accepting his would serve the same purpose.

Comment: @unit3000-21 yes and no. but i did as you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen such a notation, per se.  The closest I've seen is something like:

> Let $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ be $\sigma$-algebras, with $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{G}$.

That is, using $\subset$ (to indicate containment as sets), where it is made clear elsewhere (or from context) that the sets in question are $\sigma$-algebras.